# matlab function strel("line") to python

Tags: python, matlab, image-processing, image-morphology

I want to use the matlab function strel("line") in python

I found python library like **scikit-learn / opencv / mahotas**

but I can't find it.

finally, I found similar function in **pymorph 'seline'** but it is different to matlab strel function.

---

specifically, I want to use(or implement) strel("line") and **rotate it.**

like strel("line", length, **degree**)

---

Matlab example

```
a = strel("line",5,0)
b = strel("line",5,30)
c = strel("line",5,45)
```

output is

[image]

[image]

[image]

like this.

Anyone who knows the algorithm of matlab's strel("line",length,degree) function or python library equal to strel("line",length,degree), please let me know. thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this kind of question you can always check the code provided by the project Octave.

Using [this link](https://sourceforge.net/p/octave/image/ci/d85ddd5300a9cfaa759451c989d008e1d2eb8c7b/tree/inst/@strel/strel.m#l429) you can see how the function `strel` is implemented in Octave.

The following code is entirely extracted from the Octave's strel function and correspond to the case `strel('line')`:

```
## Parameters (degrees and linelenght)
degrees = 30
linelen = 5


## Line length are always odd, to center strel at the middle of the line.
## We look it as a diameter of a circle with given slope
deg90 = mod (degrees, 90);
if (deg90 > 45)
   alpha = pi * (90 - deg90) / 180;
else
   alpha = pi * deg90 / 180;
endif
   ray = (linelen - 1)/2;

## We are interested only in the discrete rectangle which contains the diameter
## However we focus our attention to the bottom left quarter of the circle,
## because of the central symmetry.
c = round (ray * cos (alpha)) + 1;
r = round (ray * sin (alpha)) + 1;

## Line rasterization
line = false (r, c);
m = tan (alpha);
x = [1:c];
y = r - fix (m .* (x - 0.5));
indexes = sub2ind ([r c], y, x);
line(indexes) = true;

## We view the result as 9 blocks.
# Preparing blocks
linestrip = line(1, 1:c - 1);
linerest = line(2:r, 1:c - 1);
z = false (r - 1, c);

# Assemblying blocks
SE.nhood =  vertcat (
    horzcat (z, linerest(end:-1:1,end:-1:1)),
    horzcat (linestrip, true, linestrip(end:-1:1,end:-1:1)),
    horzcat (linerest, z(end:-1:1,end:-1:1))
    );

# Rotate/transpose/flip?
sect = fix (mod (degrees, 180) / 45);
switch (sect)
    case 1, SE.nhood = transpose (SE.nhood);
    case 2, SE.nhood = rot90 (SE.nhood, 1);
    case 3, SE.nhood = fliplr (SE.nhood);
    otherwise, # do nothing
endswitch

SE
```